# SQL inner join performance issues

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, inner-join

I have a WordPress installation and I'm making a custom plugin. My plugin stores a good bit of usermeta. I'm using an inner join to combine data from the "users" and "usermeta" table at which point I spit the result back to my PHP script. Here's what my query looks like:

```
select
# Users table stuff
users.ID,
users.user_email,
users.display_name,

# Meta stuff

first_name.meta_value as first_name,
last_name.meta_value as last_name,
phone_number.meta_value as phone_number,
country.meta_value as country,
years_of_experience.meta_value as years_of_experience,
highest_degree_obtained.meta_value as highest_degree_obtained,
availability_for_work.meta_value as availability_for_work,
english_proficiency.meta_value as english_proficiency,
disciplines.meta_value as disciplines,
profile_picture.meta_value as profile_picture,
resume.meta_value as resume,
description.meta_value as description,
hourly_rate.meta_value as hourly_rate,
satisfaction_rating.meta_value as satisfaction_rating,
invited_projects.meta_value as invited_projects,
completed_project_count.meta_value as completed_project_count

# The table we're selecting from

from tsd_retro_users as users

# Join in our usermeta table for each individual meta value

inner join tsd_retro_usermeta first_name on users.ID = first_name.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta last_name on users.ID = last_name.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta phone_number on users.ID = phone_number.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta country on users.ID = country.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta years_of_experience on users.ID = years_of_experience.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta highest_degree_obtained on users.ID = highest_degree_obtained.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta availability_for_work on users.ID = availability_for_work.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta english_proficiency on users.ID = english_proficiency.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta disciplines on users.ID = disciplines.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta profile_picture on users.ID = profile_picture.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta resume on users.ID = resume.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta description on users.ID = description.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta hourly_rate on users.ID = hourly_rate.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta satisfaction_rating on users.ID = satisfaction_rating.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta invited_projects on users.ID = invited_projects.user_id
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta completed_project_count on users.ID = completed_project_count.user_id


# Define our select stipulations

where 
(users.ID = 20)
and
(first_name.meta_key = 'first_name')
and
(last_name.meta_key = 'last_name')
and
(phone_number.meta_key = 'phone_number')
and
(country.meta_key = 'country')
and
(years_of_experience.meta_key = 'years_of_experience')
and
(highest_degree_obtained.meta_key = 'highest_degree_obtained')
and
(availability_for_work.meta_key = 'availability_for_work')
and
(english_proficiency.meta_key = 'english_proficiency')
and
(disciplines.meta_key = 'disciplines')
and
(profile_picture.meta_key = 'profile_picture')
and
(resume.meta_key = 'resume')
and
(description.meta_key = 'description')
and
(hourly_rate.meta_key = 'hourly_rate')
and
(satisfaction_rating.meta_key = 'satisfaction_rating')
and
(invited_projects.meta_key = 'invited_projects')
and
(completed_project_count.meta_key = 'completed_project_count')
```

As you can see, I inner join the usermeta table for each value that I'm trying to obtain from the database. It all seems to work fine, but after a certain number of inner joins, the query seems to slow to a crawl. Right now, the above query is taking about a second on average, and I only have about twenty users in my user table.

My question is: what are the performance ramifications of inner joins? Is there a better way to run the above query and achieve the same result?

Comment: you don't need to join same table multiple times. imho it is almost ridiculous

Comment: How can I get multiple row values then from the usermeta table in WordPress without multiple joins? I need to be able to get around 10 - 20 rows from the usermeta table, all with different keys in the meta_key column...

Comment: almost ridiculous?  Its beyond ridiculous. To join the same table on multiple fields you and `AND` followed by the next field, not another join.  But surely you don't need to join on that many fields...that's redonkulous.

Comment: Alright guys I get that it's ridiculous, but my entire question is asking how to improve my query, not how many items you can find wrong with it. I'm asking for help here and constructive input, not belittling of my current code.

Comment: Well, I can understand you both: It is clearly overdone, and you need a solution. You seem to want to join two tables, so you will need one join with one comparison, that should be all. Something like: `SELECT * FROM users, tsd_retro_usermeta WHERE users.ID = tsd_retro_usermeta.user_id` just to show it can also be done without a real join.

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns Before you continue, you should definitely read up on relational databases, what to do and what *not* to do. No one is belittling you but you clearly have very little experience using databases and the reading will certainly help you immensely in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select
# Users table stuff
users.ID,
users.user_email,
users.display_name,

# Meta stuff

MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='first_name' THEN meta_table.first_name ELSE NULL END) as first_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='last_name' THEN meta_table.last_name ELSE NULL END) as last_name,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='phone_number' THEN meta_table.phone_number ELSE NULL END) as phone_number,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='country' THEN meta_table.country ELSE NULL END) as country,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='years_of_experience' THEN meta_table.years_of_experience ELSE NULL END) as years_of_experience,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='highest_degree_obtained' THEN meta_table.highest_degree_obtained ELSE NULL END) as highest_degree_obtained,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='availability_for_work' THEN meta_table.availability_for_work ELSE NULL END) as availability_for_work,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='english_proficiency' THEN meta_table.english_proficiency ELSE NULL END) as english_proficiency,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='disciplines' THEN meta_table.disciplines ELSE NULL END) as disciplines,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='profile_picture' THEN meta_table.profile_picture ELSE NULL END) as profile_picture,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='resume' THEN meta_table.resume ELSE NULL END)    as resume,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='description' THEN meta_table.description ELSE NULL END) as description,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='hourly_rate' THEN meta_table.hourly_rate ELSE NULL END) as hourly_rate,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='satisfaction_rating' THEN meta_table.satisfaction_rating ELSE NULL END) as satisfaction_rating,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='invited_projects' THEN meta_table.invited_projects ELSE NULL END)  as invited_projects,
MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='completed_project_count' THEN meta_table.completed_project_count ELSE NULL END) as completed_project_count

# The table we're selecting from

from tsd_retro_users as users

# Join in our usermeta table for each individual meta value

inner join tsd_retro_usermeta  as meta_table
ON  users.ID = meta_table.user_id

# Define our select stipulations

where 
(users.ID = 20)
GROUP BY users.ID
```

And as soon as we use php you can do this way:

```
$requiredMetaFields = array(
'first_name',
'last_name',
'phone_number',
'country',
'years_of_experience',
'highest_degree_obtained',
'availability_for_work',
'english_proficiency',
'disciplines',
'profile_picture',
'resume',
'description',
'hourly_rate',
'satisfaction_rating',
'invited_projects',
'completed_project_count'
);

$query = "select
    users.ID,
    users.user_email,
    users.display_name,";

foreach($requiredMetaFields as $metafield) {
$query .= "MAX(CASE WHEN meta_table.meta_key='$metafield' THEN meta_table.$metafield ELSE NULL END) as $metafield, ";
}
$query =substr($query,0,-1);
$query .= "from tsd_retro_users as users
inner join tsd_retro_usermeta  as meta_table
ON  users.ID = meta_table.user_id
where 
(users.ID = 20)
GROUP BY users.ID";
```

Edited syntax errors

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error at line nine starting at the "THEN" statement in the first case. I'm not familiar with SQL case syntax so I'm not sure what's wrong here.

Comment: The update only has the PHP version of the query? Doesn't seem to have the initial query anymore?

Comment: it is too long to copy paste, wait a sec

Comment: @ThoughtSpaceDesigns check again. But you should better use query string php generation. it is simple and clear code.

Comment: Got it. Much faster. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I also have a separate query that has a more in depth where clause comparing meta values. How could I use the above method that you posted if I were to have a WHERE clause that checked against meta values? for example WHERE hourly_rate < 50?

Comment: you can add `HAVING  hourly_rate < 50` after `GROUP BY`

Comment: can I do multiple having clauses? For example:

having hourly_rate < 50 
and
having satisfaction_rating > 80