# Select with unknow fields

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have to make a mysql select from a wordpress database :

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title AS post_title,
        responsable.meta_value AS responsable,
        nif_cliente.meta_value AS nif_cliente,
        CONCAT_WS(' ',contactos_0_nombre.meta_value,CONCAT('<br><br>',contactos_1_nombre.meta_value)) AS contactos,
        tipo_de_empresa.meta_value AS tipo_de_empresa,
        tipo_cliente.meta_value AS tipo_cliente

        FROM wp_posts

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS responsable 
        ON wp_posts.ID = responsable.post_id AND responsable.meta_key='responsable'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS tipo_de_empresa
        ON wp_posts.ID = tipo_de_empresa.post_id AND tipo_de_empresa.meta_key='tipo_de_empresa'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS nif_cliente
        ON wp_posts.ID = nif_cliente.post_id AND nif_cliente.meta_key='nif_cliente'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS contactos_0_nombre
        ON wp_posts.ID = contactos_0_nombre.post_id AND contactos_0_nombre.meta_key='contactos_0_nombre'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS contactos_1_nombre
        ON wp_posts.ID = contactos_1_nombre.post_id AND contactos_1_nombre.meta_key='contactos_1_nombre'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS tipo_cliente
        ON wp_posts.ID = tipo_cliente.post_id AND tipo_cliente.meta_key='tipo_cliente'

        WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'clientes'"
```

I want to concate contactos_n_nombre. I can write it manual but 'n' it's dinamic (i don't know how much it is) It can be 0 if there are only one contact, but can be 1000 if this client have more contact methods.

How can i make it to search how many contactos have one client, and concate all of them

Thanks

Comment: Can't help much here this is not relational design.

Comment: I use this solution to make it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26319613/improving-a-query-using-a-lot-of-inner-joins-to-wp-postmeta-a-key-value-table

Comment: yes, but in your case you should better think about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773960/sql-inner-join-performance-issues and compare how to combine both

Comment: But it works fine now. I only want to know how to concate N fields if i don't know N. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function. You may need to adjust this for your situation, but the basic idea is:

Set up the database JOIN as:

```
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS contactosdb ON wp_posts.ID = contactosdb.post_id
```

Then use the following in your SELECT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(contactosdb.meta_value SEPARATOR '<br><br>') AS contactos
```

Comment: Thanks @bobdye

I think that GROUP_CAT join fields with the same name.

But I have fields with different names: contactos_0.meta_value, contactos_1.meta_value, contactos_2.meta_value..... contactos_N.meta_value, and N it's dynamic, and i don't know this number. I need to join all contactos_N.metavalue. Thanks again